# Integrate using \[Esc] int \[Esc]

Tags: syntax, keyboard

I like writing integrals symbolically instead of using Integrate[]. I suddenly seem to not be able to do this and am confused. I type `\[Esc] int \[Esc]` then `\[Ctrl] + _` for my lower bound, and [online](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) it says use `\[Ctrl] + %` for the upper bound, but nothing happens. I've also tried using `\[Ctrl] + ^` which [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html) says it is a superscript, and that gets me somewhere. However, I get a syntax error.

So for the `\[Ctrl] + ^` case, I'm typing `\[Esc]int\[Esc]\[Ctrl]+_0\[rightarrow]\[Ctrl]+^1 2 \[Esc]dd\[Esc]x` and I get the syntax error

```
Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed .
```

I've also tried putting parenthesis around the integrand, but it doesn't help. On the screen it looks fine:[image]

So why doesn't the `\[Ctrl] + %` do anything? And ultimately, how do I get this symbolic integral to evaluate? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should use `\[Ctrl] + %` for upper bound, it works for me (M10.1, Windows 8.1). `\[Ctrl] + ^` is a superscript, it's an index.

Comment: Try Ctrl-5.  On a US English keyboard the % sign is above 5.  What is your keyboard layout?

Comment: `\[Esc] int \[Esc] (\[Ctrl] + -) 0 (\[Ctrl] + 5) x \[RightArrow] Sin[y] \[Esc] dd \[Esc] y (\[Shift] + \[Return])` returned the expected `1 - Cos[x]` (M10.0.1 Win7x64). Standard US keyboard.

Comment: When I type (in my US keyboard, M10.0, Windows 8.1) `\[Ctrl]+%` literally nothing happens. I have typed these several times in the past and have no issues. Even when I run old notebooks I see this formatting and it runs fine.

Comment: Maybe a restart of windows or the kernel? Failing that I'm pressed to suggest anything else.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all the help! I think what I was doing was typing a space between my lower bound and upper bound.If you type in your lower bound, then immediately hit `\[Ctrl]+%`, you get the upper bound and it's all fine. I've  tried a few combos with upper bound first and I think it's just very finicky. But I do really like the `\[Ctrl] -5` trick as the best result which is  why I voted it the best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of adding first a subscript and then a *separate* superscript, you need to add joint pair. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>%</kbd> moves between the sub- and superscripts, but the actual keyboard shortcut may be dependent on your keyboard layout.  Also try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd>.

You can look up the shortcut next to the Insert → Typesetting → Opposite Position menu item.

On my computer I see <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd> in the menu.

Answer (score 9):

If you cannot resolve the keyboard behavior try an alternate input form; I propose:

<kbd>Esc</kbd>`dintt`<kbd>Esc</kbd>

To input:

[image]

Then use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move between the [`Placeholder`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Placeholder.html) fields.

Comment: Strangely if one types '[esc]din', this is not offered as a completion

Comment: @m_goldberg An oversight perhaps?  It is shown in a Tooltip in the **Basic Math Assistant** palette.

Comment: Yes, it would appear so. I'm thinking of reporting it to WRI.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. The `\[Tab]` trick is neato.